# Dynamically adding checkbox to DataGrid in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding check box dynamically to DataGrid. I want to generate event for this dynamically generated checkbox? Any suggestions on how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
  void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
  }

  checkbox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.Check_Clicked);
```